# How to read text from an Excel table range using MS Graph?

Tags: excel, rest, microsoft-graph-api

I have previously been reading the text from a table in excel using the following URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/my-folder%5Cmy-workbook.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets('MyWorksheet')/tables('MyTable')/range/text
```

Now that is giving me a 200 response with this content:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.Json"
}
```

I can access the range using the same URL but without the `\text` segment. For example the requests to the following URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/my-folder%5Cmy-workbook.xlsx:/workbook/worksheets('MyWorksheet')/tables('MyTable')/range
```

result in:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#workbookRange",
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.workbookRange",
    "@odata.id": "/users('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')/drive/root/workbook/worksheets(%27%7Bxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx%7D%27)/tables(%2719%27)/range()",
    "address": "MyWorksheet!C6:BB18",
    "addressLocal": "MyWorksheet!C6:BB18",
    "cellCount": 676,
    "columnCount": 52,
    "columnHidden": false,
    "columnIndex": 2,
    "formulas": [ ... ],
    "formulasLocal": [ ... ],
    "formulasR1C1": [ ... ],
    "hidden": false,
    "numberFormat": [ ... ],
    "rowCount": 13,
    "rowHidden": false,
    "rowIndex": 5,
    "text": [
        [
            "Text",
            "From",
            "The",
            "Range",
            ...,
        ]
    ]
    "values": [ ... ],
    "valueTypes": [ ....]
}
```

The `text` property is present and contains the expected data.

The [MS Graph documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/range) includes a text property on  the range resource.

As stated above, I believe this was working earlier, so I'm assuming this is due to some bug / change / limitaion in MS Graph.

Can anyone advise how to read the text from that table range directly (and/or why I am getting that response)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` is a property of the `microsoft.graph.workbookRang`, but not an endpoint. I'm not sure how/if `/range/text` could have worked in the past but I wouldn't have expected it to.

As for returning just the text, you can use the [`$select`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#select-parameter) query parameter:

```
/me/drive/root:/{path}:/workbook/worksheets('{id}')/tables('{id}')/range?$select=text
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been able to confirm that the original method was working for the past 6 months plus, up until very recently. I guess we were relying on an undocumented feature we shouldn't have been using.